# Numpy: how to access axis 0 elements in a (2, N) matrix to be used as function arguments

Tags: python, numpy

I have a Numpy 2D matrix with shape `(2, N)`.  Let `arr` be:

```
arr = np.array([[2, 4, 6], [10, 20, 30]])
print(arr.shape)
arr
(2, 3)
array([[ 2,  4,  6],
       [10, 20, 30]])
```

If I have a function that, say, adds two numbers (yes, I know we can use broadcasting, but that's not the point here), I'd like to be able to access the `axis 0` elements in `arr` to pass into the function.

For example:

```
def add_two(a, b):
    return a + b
```

How do I **use iteration** to access the pairs `(2, 10), (4, 20), and (6, 30)` to be used as arguments for `add_two()`?

For example:

```
for elem in arr.shape[1]:
    print('The sum is', add_two(arr...))
```

Desired output:

```
The sum is 12
The sum is 24
The sum is 36
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the expected behavior if the two arrays have **different shapes**? And is addition of **only two** arrays the requirement here, or any arbitrary amount of arrays? Also, should the correct answer be optimized for arrays of shape `(2, N)` specifically, or should the correct answer assume **any shape** and provide a more general answer?

Comment: Assume that they are the same shape.  Yes, we are adding two numbers inside of a (2, N) matrix.  Optimization is not a concern.

Comment: Kudos! This is a well-phrased question. As can be seen from the number of answers it elicited, your MRE made it easy for folks to reproduce and solve your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy.

```
for (a,b) in arr.T:
    print('The sum is', add_two(a,b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[2, 4, 6], [10, 20, 30]])

def add_two(a, b):
    return a + b
    
for vals in zip(*arr):
    print('The sum is', add_two(vals[0], vals[1]))
```

The crux of this is zip(*arr).

**Explanation:**
zip takes an arbitrary number of arguments and "zips" them together. Ex: zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]) outputs a zip object in the form [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]. The * operator before arr "unpacks" the values of arr into zip, so zip(*arr) becomes zip([2, 4, 6], [10, 20, 30])

Comment: Rather than `add_two(vals[0], vals[1])`, you might find it more natural to phrase it as `add_two(*vals)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your column index iteration could be written as:

```
In [242]: for elem in range(arr.shape[1]):
     ...:     print('The sum is', add_two(arr[0,elem],arr[1,elem]))
     ...:     
The sum is 12
The sum is 24
The sum is 36
```

While iterating on indices is allowed in python, iteration on that values is more idiomatic (and using `enumerate` if you also need the indices).  So:

```
In [243]: for i,j in zip(arr[0,:],arr[1,:]):
     ...:     print('The sum is', add_two(i,j))
     ...:     
The sum is 12
The sum is 24
The sum is 36
```

`zip(a,b)` is a list form of `transpose`.

Iteration on an array treats the array as a list (on the first dimension).  Transpose makes the second dimension the iteration one:

```
In [244]: for i,j in arr.T:
     ...:     print('The sum is', add_two(i,j))
The sum is 12
The sum is 24
The sum is 36
```

But since you already have a 2d array, you can just use `sum` with the axis specification:

```
In [245]: arr.sum(axis=0)
Out[245]: array([12, 24, 36])
```